# Function doesn't get variable value?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm writing an automation script that will collect data from 4 emails that arrive during a day and sending a report email at the end of the day, I already figured out how to append text file that will be sent and how to search email for specific string that tell me if everything's alright.

But I have an issue. I put some code into Subs and Functions and it stopped work. itm.Body is not visible in Function CheckSafeSet, and what strange Else don't run if IF isn't ture.

Please help. If you have any suggestions to do it differently, smarter better simpler please tell me

Thanks Michal

```
Public Sub AppendTextFiles(safeset As String)

    Open "C:\AppSupport\testfilew.txt" For Append As #1
    Print #1, safeset
    Close #1

End Sub
Function CheckSafeSet(safeset As String)
            MsgBox ("1")
            MsgBox (itm.Body)
            If itm.Body Like safeset Then
                MsgBox ("2")
                Call AppendTextFiles("adfsdfasdfsergedgrrt")
            Else:
                MsgBox ("FAIL")
            End If
End Function



Public Sub process_email(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

'Strings - Savegroups
Dim d1000i As String
Dim d1200i As String
Dim l0001i As String
l0001i = "*Savegroup: VNX_UK_NDMP_00:01*"
Dim l2000i As String


Dim lonparch01 As String
'lonparch01 = "*pnwifsvbbup03.r3-core.r3.aig.net:/root_vdm_1/vol_lonparch01_snap 42927:nsrndmp_save: Successfully done*"
lonparch01 = "*NDMP*"
Dim new_msg As MailItem
        If itm.Body Like l0001i Then
        MsgBox (itm.Body)
            Call CheckSafeSet(lonparch01)
        Else:

        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: So start taking the code out of the functions and subs one by one until it works. Then you know which method is wrong...did you try testing?

Comment: you need to pass itm to the CheckSafeSet function and remove the : in your else clause

Comment: Well _AppendTextFiles_ Function is not an issue for now. The problem is in _CheckSafeSet_ Function. I could take out code out of it but actually I want it in. If I will take out code it will work but I will make a step back. Thank You

Comment: How to pass _itm_ to the function? Im really fresh in VBA. Im sorry

Comment: Add it to the signature CheckSafeSet(safeset As String, itm As Outlook.MailItem) and then when you call it Call CheckSafeSet(lonparch01, itm)

Comment: It's alive! Thanks A lot !

Comment: @Byron it has been done!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have not passed the itm object to the CheckSafeSet Function.   YOu need to add itm As Outlook.MailItem to the signature of the CheckSafeSet Function and then pass the itm object

```
Public Sub AppendTextFiles(safeset As String)

    Open "C:\AppSupport\testfilew.txt" For Append As #1
    Print #1, safeset
    Close #1

End Sub
Function CheckSafeSet(safeset As String, itm As Outlook.MailItem)
            MsgBox ("1")
            MsgBox (itm.Body)
            If itm.Body Like safeset Then
                MsgBox ("2")
                Call AppendTextFiles("adfsdfasdfsergedgrrt")
            Else
                MsgBox ("FAIL")
            End If
End Function



Public Sub process_email(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

'Strings - Savegroups
Dim d1000i As String
Dim d1200i As String
Dim l0001i As String
l0001i = "*Savegroup: VNX_UK_NDMP_00:01*"
Dim l2000i As String


Dim lonparch01 As String
'lonparch01 = "*pnwifsvbbup03.r3-core.r3.aig.net:/root_vdm_1/vol_lonparch01_snap 42927:nsrndmp_save: Successfully done*"
lonparch01 = "*NDMP*"
Dim new_msg As MailItem
        If itm.Body Like l0001i Then
        MsgBox (itm.Body)
            Call CheckSafeSet(lonparch01, itm)
        Else

        End If

End Sub
```